# How to create this wavy animation in Blender?

Tags: animation

The following animation was [created in Cinema 4D](https://zine.3dfordesigners.com/issue/3d-art-kickstart-go-with-the-flow). How to do this in Blender?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Plane -> Subsurf modifier + wave modifier (Y-constrained) + wave modifier (X-constrained)

Tweak values to your liking.

[image]

[image]